# How to change Emacs' word movement behaviour?

Tags: motion, config, words

I want to do this on `forward-word`: (`|` shows the cursor position)

Normal Behaviour:

```
int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    int a = 45|;
    printf|("%i", a);
}
```

What I want to do:

```
//forward-word first
int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    int a = 45|;|
    printf("%i", a);
}

//forward-word second
int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    int a = 45;|
    printf|("%i", a);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use these commands to skip words but stop around symbols,

```lisp
(defun reluctant-forward (&optional arg)
  "Skip spaces and tabs following the point, then move past all
characters with the same syntax class.

Do it ARG times if ARG is positive, or -ARG times in the opposite
direction if ARG is negative. ARG defaults to 1."
  (interactive "^p")
  (if (> arg 0)
      (dotimes (_ arg)
        (when (looking-at-p "[ \t]")
          (skip-chars-forward " \t"))
        (unless (= (point) (point-max))
          (forward-same-syntax)))
    (dotimes (_ (- arg))
      (when (looking-back "[ \t]")
        (skip-chars-backward " \t"))
      (unless (= (point) (point-min))
        (forward-same-syntax -1)))))

(defun reluctant-backward (&optional arg)
  "Skip spaces and tabs preceding the point, then move before all
characters with the same syntax class.

Do it ARG times if ARG is positive, or -ARG times in the opposite
direction if ARG is negative. ARG defaults to 1."
  (interactive "^p")
  (reluctant-forward (- arg)))
```

and I've bound them to `M-left` and `M-right`:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<right>") #'reluctant-forward) ; replaces ‘right-word’.
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<left>") #'reluctant-backward) ; replaces ‘left-word’.
```

Here are the places where `reluctant-forward` would place the point if called repeatedly starting from within the square brackets

```
int main(int argc, char *args[|])|
|{|
    |int| a| =| 45|;|
    |printf|(|"|%i|"|,| a|)|;|
|}|
```

Notice that as it is it stops at the beginning of the first word that follows a newline (e.g. at the beginning of `printf`), differently from what you asked. I should be able to fix that if you want.

---

**Update**

I thought I had to fiddle with syntax classes, instead it was just a matter of adding the newline to the characters to skip.

```lisp
(defun reluctant-forward (&optional arg)
  "Skip whitespace following the point, then move past all
characters with the same syntax class.

Do it ARG times if ARG is positive, or -ARG times in the opposite
direction if ARG is negative. ARG defaults to 1."
  (interactive "^p")
  (if (> arg 0)
      (dotimes (_ arg)
        (when (looking-at-p "[ \t\n]")
          (skip-chars-forward " \t\n"))
        (unless (= (point) (point-max))
          (forward-same-syntax)))
    (dotimes (_ (- arg))
      (when (looking-back "[ \t\n]")
        (skip-chars-backward " \t\n"))
      (unless (= (point) (point-min))
        (forward-same-syntax -1)))))

(defun reluctant-backward (&optional arg)
  "Skip whitespace preceding the point, then move before all
characters with the same syntax class.

Do it ARG times if ARG is positive, or -ARG times in the opposite
direction if ARG is negative. ARG defaults to 1."
  (interactive "^p")
  (reluctant-forward (- arg)))
```

Stops from `|[])` to `printf|`:

```lisp
int main(int argc, char *args|[|])|
{|
    int| a| =| 45|;|
    printf|("%i", a);
}
```

---

**Update 2**

Not as tested as the other version (I might have missed some corner cases) but it seems to do what you want

```lisp
(defun reluctant-forward (&optional arg)
  "Move point to the end of the next word or string of
non-word-constituent characters.

Do it ARG times if ARG is positive, or -ARG times in the opposite
direction if ARG is negative. ARG defaults to 1."
  (interactive "^p")
  (if (> arg 0)
      (dotimes (_ arg)
        ;; First, skip whitespace ahead of point
        (when (looking-at-p "[ \t\n]")
          (skip-chars-forward " \t\n"))
        (unless (= (point) (point-max))
          ;; Now, if we're at the beginning of a word, skip it…
          (if (looking-at-p "\\sw")
              (skip-syntax-forward "w")
            ;; …otherwise it means we're at the beginning of a string of
            ;; symbols. Then move forward to another whitespace char,
            ;; word-constituent char, or to the end of the buffer.
            (if (re-search-forward "\n\\|\\s-\\|\\sw" nil t)
                (backward-char)
              (goto-char (point-max))))))
    (dotimes (_ (- arg))
      (when (looking-back "[ \t\n]")
        (skip-chars-backward " \t\n"))
      (unless (= (point) (point-min))
        (if (looking-back "\\sw")
            (skip-syntax-backward "w")
          (if (re-search-backward "\n\\|\\s-\\|\\sw" nil t)
              (forward-char)
            (goto-char (point-min))))))))

(defun reluctant-backward (&optional arg)
  "Move point to the beginning of the previous word or string of
non-word-constituent characters.

Do it ARG times if ARG is positive, or -ARG times in the opposite
direction if ARG is negative. ARG defaults to 1."
  (interactive "^p")
  (reluctant-forward (- arg)))
```

Stops (starting from the beginning, and using `reluctant-forward` with positive `ARG`):

```
int| main|(|int| argc|,| char| *|args|[])|
{|
    int| a| =| 45|;|
    printf|("%|i|",| a|);|
}|
```

Comment: Yeah, this is so close to what I want actually.
`
|int| main|(|int| argc|,| char| *args|[])|
{|
    int| a| =| 45|;|
    printf|("%|i|",| a|);|
}|
This is exactly what I want.
`

Comment: @shigi see the latest update

Comment: Yep, it works great. Thank you so much.